# how can I run the result of this powershell script... I can't get the last pipe to output the versions of java

Tags: java, powershell, report, version

I'm looking to get the java versions of all the Java on the machine.

```
 Get-ChildItem 'C:\Program Files*' -Include java.exe -Recurse | % { $_ -version }
```

i'm able to get the results however am not able to *run* the commands to get the actual versions back.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_241\bin\java.exe -version
C:\Program Files\Vertiv\DSView 4\j2sdk\bin\java.exe -version
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe -version
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath_target_3553135156\java.exe -version
```

any other options appreciated.

Comment: In short: to invoke an executable whose name or path is stored in a variable or quoted string, you must use `&`, the [call (execute) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-)

Comment: Therefore: `& $_ -version`